# How long is an epic?

Tags: terminology, genre

My dictionary had the following definitions for the word "epic":

> epic: telling a story about a hero or about exciting events or adventures

and

> epic: a long book, movie, etc., that usually tells a story about exciting events or adventures

I wanted to know, in practice, how many hours long does a movie have to be in order to be called an epic? Is there a set of time periods corresponding to the length of an epic movie? Or are there any other criteria involved in defining such a movie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Epics are often defined not in terms of length, but in terms of plot - an epic typically is about an [Epic Hero](http://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/documents/Epic.pdf) that encounters adversity and must overcome it. In this sense, a lot of works in many different media are considered epics - works all the way from Gilgamesh to Beowulf to [Star Wars](http://users.clas.ufl.edu/agordon/starwars.htm) have been considered epics.

Comment: Another requirement seems to be "doesn't happen in present day", but maybe it's just that I can't think of one that does.

Comment: @Walt There is the book "Jitterbug Perfume" by Tom Robbins.  In the introduction he says it's an epic because "it begins in ancient Bohemia an doesn't conclude until 9 o'clock tonight, Paris time," so that includes the present day.

Answer (score 6):

Source [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_film):

> **Many writers may refer to any film that is "long" (over two hours) as an epic**.

But mainly epic came from poetic genre

Source [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_film):

> When described as "epic" because of content, an epic movie is often
>   set during a time of war or other societal crisis, while usually
>   covering a longer span of time sometimes throughout entire generations
>   coming and passing away, in terms of both the events depicted and the
>   running time of the film. Such films usually have a historical
>   setting, although fantasy or science fiction settings have become
>   common in recent decades. The central conflict of the film is usually
>   seen as having far-reaching effects, often changing the course of
>   history. The main characters' actions are often central to the
>   resolution of the societal conflict.
>
> In its classification of films by genre, the American Film Institute
>   limits the genre to historical films such as Ben-Hur. However, film
>   scholars such as Constantine Santas are willing to extend the label to
>   science-fiction films such as 2001: A Space Odyssey and Star Wars.[2]
>   Nickolas Haydock suggests that "Surely one of the hardest film genres
>   to define is that of the "epic" film, encompassing such examples as
>   Ben-Hur, Gone with the Wind....and more recently, 300 and the Star
>   Wars films...none of these comes from literary epics per se, and there
>   is little that links them with one another. Among those who espouse
>   film genre studies, epic is one of the most despised and ignored
>   genres"[3] Finally, although the American Movie Channel formally
>   defines epic films as historical films, they nonetheless state the
>   epic film may be combined with the genre of science-fiction and cite
>   Star Wars as an example.[4]
>
> Stylistically, films classed as epic usually employ spectacular
>   settings and specially designed costumes, often accompanied by a
>   sweeping musical score, and an ensemble cast of bankable stars. Epics
>   are usually among the most expensive of films to produce. They often
>   use on-location filming, authentic period costumes, and action scenes
>   on a massive scale. Biographical films may be less lavish versions of
>   this genre.
>
> Many writers may refer to any film that is "long" (over two hours) as
>   an epic, making the definition epic a matter of dispute, and raise
>   questions as to whether it is a "genre" at all. As Roger Ebert put it,
>   in his "Great Movies" article on Lawrence of Arabia:[5]
>
> The word epic in recent years has become synonymous with big budget B
>   picture. What you realize watching Lawrence of Arabia is that the word
>   epic refers not to the cost or the elaborate production, but to the
>   size of the ideas and vision. Werner Herzog's Aguirre: The Wrath of
>   God didn't cost as much as the catering in Pearl Harbor, but it is an
>   epic, and Pearl Harbor is not.

[More](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_film)...